# Как добавить ссылки на соцсети в моем андроид-приложении?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-button, android-on-click

Я новичок, хочу в свое приложение добавить кнопки на соцсети.
Приложение - это информационный ресурс описывающий одну организацию и соответственно, необходимо вставить кнопки отправляющие на страницы этой компании в соцсетях.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Не совсем понятен ваш вопрос, с чем конкретно у вас возникла сложность? У вас проблема с описанием кнопки в XML? Или же с написанием кода, который должен быть вызван при нажатии на кнопку? Приведите участок кода, который у вас уже написан, и напишите подробнее, что у вас не получилось сделать? Отредактировать вопрос можно по кнопке [edit] под вопросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы открыть произвольную ссылку по нажатию на кнопку, задайте обработчик для этой кнопки, в котором запустите [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters) с действием [`ACTION_VIEW`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_VIEW):

```kotlin
val myButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.myButton)
myButton.setOnClickListener {
    startActivity(Intent(ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://example.org")))
}
```

В официальном гайде [есть пример](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Browser), в котором показано, как запустить браузер по ссылке.

Comment: Да, спасибо, для обработки ссылки на сайт работает обычный обработчик через интент.
'public void showNet(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.somethings.com/"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }'

А как сделать чтобы ссылка открывалась в установленном приложении соцсетей? То есть ссылка на ВК открывалась в ВК и тд?

Comment: Точно так же. Если в приложении социальных сетей реализовано открытие соответствующих ссылок (настроен intent filter), то система Андроид может предложить, через какое приложение открывать ссылку, либо откроет ссылку через то приложение, которое уже выбрано по-умолчанию.

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает как надо. Достаточно интента со ссылкой. Просто я перед этим читал устаревшую литературу и видео давнее, так там трех этажный код на все это.